# Does anybody know what kind of creepy-crawly this is?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

My son found this caterpillar in our garden in the UK. Have asked multiple people with more knowledge in this area who have been unable to identify it. looking for any help?

Having looked online the closest I have found are moth caterpillars, but not found anything like this one. I hope you can see from the images it has 'whiskers' around its head and around 1/4 of its body but no further, a yellow squishy looking head and quite muted green and black body.

It's the 'whiskers' (not sure of the proper term for them) not extending to its full length that I think is the most identifiable feature and that is what I have been unable to find when looking online.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you identified the plant it was found on, if possible?

Comment: We think it was a persicaria, it seems to be eating those leaves in the tank anyway.

Comment: It looks to my eye like some variety of tent caterpillar (though I've never seen that exact pattern before), have you noticed any silky structures in any nearby trees or shrubs? Also, if you still have it can we get a picture of its lovely face?